# Nested UITapGestureRecognizers

Tags: iphone, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

If I have several views stacked one on top of the other (all subviews of each other) where each one has a UITapGestureRecognizer attached to it.
How can I make sure that the highest visible view received the gesture and not the furthest ancestor?

Answer (score 0):

The tap gesture is only valid for the current view. Further the frame of your current view(-controller). You can create a blank view over the hole screen and put in there your current view lets say `200x200 px`. (essentially it is both in the same view)
Now all gestures should respond to your topmost view-controller. The bad thing about that: you can't access the views below anymore.